# PDF File Size 0 byte and getting error in console

Tags: spring-boot, itext

I'm getting error when i trying to generate pdf. I've used itext pdf for creating pdf. I got following error in sts3 console.

**Error:**

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:821)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:277)
    at com.doller.flightreservation.util.PDFGenerator.generateItinerary(PDFGenerator.java:28)
    at com.doller.flightreservation.services.ReservationServiceImpl.bookFlight(ReservationServiceImpl.java:59)
    at com.doller.flightreservation.controllers.ReservationController.completeReservation(ReservationController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:438)
```

And my PDF file saved with 0 byte with proper name. But I'm getting different named file Itiniarary.pdf with blank file and file not opening.

I've share my code below:

PDFGenerator.java

```
package com.doller.flightreservation.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.doller.flightreservation.entities.Reservation;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

@Component
public class PDFGenerator {

    public void generateItinerary(Reservation reservation, String filePath) {

        Document document = new Document();

        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));

            document.open();

            document.add(generateTable(reservation));

            document.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private PdfPTable generateTable(Reservation reservation) {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Flight Itinerary"));
        cell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Flight Details"));
        cell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell);

        table.addCell("Airlines ");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getOperatingAirlines());

        table.addCell("Departure City");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getDepartureCity());

        table.addCell("Arrival City");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getArrivalCity());

        table.addCell("Flight Number");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getFlightNumber());

        table.addCell("Departure Date");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getDateOfDeparture().toString());

        table.addCell("Departure Time");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getEstimatedDepartureTime().toString());

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Passenger Details"));
        cell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell);

        table.addCell("First Name");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getFirstName());

        table.addCell("Last Name");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getLastName());

        table.addCell("Email");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getEmail());

        table.addCell("Phone");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getPhone());

        return null;
    }
}
```

EmailUtil.java

```
package com.doller.flightreservation.util;

import java.io.File;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmailUtil {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    public void sendItinerary(String toAddress, String filePath) {

        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();

        try {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            messageHelper.setTo(toAddress);
            messageHelper.setSubject("Itinerary for your Flight");
            messageHelper.setText("Please find your Itinerary attached.");
            messageHelper.addAttachment("Itinearary", new File(filePath));
            sender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

ReservationServiceImpl.java

```
package com.doller.flightreservation.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.doller.flightreservation.dto.ReservationRequest;
import com.doller.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.doller.flightreservation.entities.Passenger;
import com.doller.flightreservation.entities.Reservation;
import com.doller.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;
import com.doller.flightreservation.repos.PassengerRepository;
import com.doller.flightreservation.repos.ReservationRepository;
import com.doller.flightreservation.util.EmailUtil;
import com.doller.flightreservation.util.PDFGenerator;

@Service
public class ReservationServiceImpl implements ReservationService {

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @Autowired
    PassengerRepository passengerRepository;

    @Autowired
    ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

    @Autowired
    PDFGenerator pdfGenerator;

    @Autowired
    EmailUtil emailUtil;

    @Override
    public Reservation bookFlight(ReservationRequest request) {

        // Make Payment

        Long flightId = request.getFlightId();
        Flight flight = flightRepository.findById(flightId).get();

        Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
        passenger.setFirstName(request.getPassengerFirstName());
        passenger.setLastName(request.getPassengerLastName());
        passenger.setPhone(request.getPassengerPhone());
        passenger.setEmail(request.getPassengerEmail());

        Passenger savedPassenger = passengerRepository.save(passenger);

        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation.setFlight(flight);
        reservation.setPassenger(savedPassenger);
        reservation.setCheckedIn(false);

        Reservation savedReservation = reservationRepository.save(reservation);

        String filePath = "C:/Users/dolow/OneDrive/" + "doller_reservation_pdfs_"
                + savedReservation.getId() + ".pdf";
        pdfGenerator.generateItinerary(savedReservation, filePath);
        emailUtil.sendItinerary(passenger.getEmail(), filePath);
        System.out.println(filePath);
        return savedReservation;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `generateTable` you return the result:

```
private PdfPTable generateTable(Reservation reservation) {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cell;

    [...]

    return null;
}
```

You probably want to do

```
    return table;
```

instead.